# Set variable value from case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to count all '0' in the string after coma if value is smaller then 1.
**Example:**
I have string '0,005', the result will be 2.

Thats works fine:

```
declare @s varchar(15), @i int
Set @s='0,05'
Set @i=Len(Substring(@s, 3, Len(@s)-3));
print @i
```

But if I do so, I have an error:

```
declare @s varchar(15), @i int
Set @s='0,05'
select
  case
    when CAST(@s as decimal)<1 then set @i= Len(Substring(@s, 3, Len(@s)-3))
  end
```

Error is "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'Set'". 
What should I do?

Comment: I think it should be like `when CAST(@s as decimal)<1 then set @i = ..`

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* - it computes a *value*. It's *not* a control-flow statement.

Comment: In which case `@variable = *expr*` will work - e.g. `@i = *expr*`, in other words `@i = case when ... etc`

Answer (score 1):

Case Statement Should be like  below:

```
SET @i = CASE WHEN codition here Then result1 Else result2 END
```

And How can you CAST `0,05` into `Numeric`? It' not possible I think.

Like Below:

```
Declare @s varchar(15), @i int
Set @s='0,05'
SET @i = case when CAST(@s as decimal) < 1 then Len(Substring(@s, 3, Len(@s)-3)) End
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --Invalid Cast
```

Answer (score 1):

The other cloned answers will give a wrong result if you use value '0,011'. There will also be an issue converting to decimal.
This should return the correct result.

```
DECLARE @s varchar(15), @i int
Set @s='0,05'
SET @i = case when @s like '%[1-9]%,%' or @s not like '%,%[1-9]%' then 0
              else PatIndex('%[1-9]%',stuff(@s, 1, charindex(',', @s), '')) - 1
         end
SELECT @i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(15), @i int
set @s = '0,05'
set @i = case
           when @s like '0,%' then patindex('%[1-9]%', substring(@s, 3, len(@s) - 2)) - 1
           else 0
         end
select @i
```

Comment: how is this different from @VigneshKumar's answer ? It returns the same wrong result and the code is identical

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, the code is not identical.But, David, you should add some description of what your code does.

Comment: There is no difference; I was posting at the same time as Vignesh

Comment: Edited answer is a little more elegant :)

Comment: ,01 and 00,001 and 0,0 all give funky results. Also if you add a space in front of the value ' 0,05'

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @s varchar(15), @i int
Set @s='0,05'
SET @i = case when LEN(@s) > 1 then Len(Substring(@s, 3, Len(@s)-3)) End
PRINT @i
```